# How to center views vertically as if there were no navigation title?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationview, swiftui-navigationstack

I have a `NavigationStack`/`NavigationView` which loads its links. When it's loading or contains no links, I want to display a view centered in the screen to inform the user.

However, when there's a navigation title (`.navigationTitle()`), it takes space from the other views and centers the remaining content lower on the screen than the true center (and I think it looks more correct in the true center).

Is there a way to have the views ignore the navigation title and center in the true center?

I tried nesting everything in a `GeometryReader` and using `proxy.size.height / 2` as the y position, but this still doesn't fix it. The only fix I did find was using `proxy.size.height / 2 - geo.safeAreaInsets.top - geo.safeAreaInsets.bottom`, but this seems hacky, and I'm wondering if there's a better solution.

Image references: [Without title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4csOQ.png) vs [with title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhORE.png)

```swift
var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
        ProgressView()
            .controlSize(.large)
            .navigationTitle("Feed") // only difference
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to fix this is by overlaying the `ProgressView` on the `NavigationStack`.

```
struct TestView: View {
    @State var feed: String? = nil

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                if let feed {
                    Text(feed)
                }
                Spacer()
            }
            .navigationTitle("Feed")
        }
        .overlay {
            if feed == nil {
                ProgressView()
                    .controlSize(.large)
            }
        }
        .task {
            try? await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(2))
            feed = "Here's the deets."
        }
    }
}
```